# Record only Audio with MediaRecorder

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I want to record an audio file in .mp4 from mic.
This is my code:

```
fun startRecording() {
    recorder = MediaRecorder().apply {
        setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC)
        setOutputFile(fileName)
        try {
            prepare()
            start()
            recordingListener?.invoke(Step.RECORDING, null)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            recordingListener?.invoke(Step.ERROR, null)
            stopRecorder()
        }
    }
}

private fun stopRecorder() {
    recorder?.apply {
        stop()
        release()
        isRecording = false
    }
}
```

This is working but the generated file is considered as a video file.

I don't understand why, my back-end need an audio file and not a video file.

What can I do to record as an audio file ? Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should change the output format. It writes in the docs:

```
 /** The following formats are audio only .aac or .amr formats */

    /**
     * AMR NB file format
     * @deprecated  Deprecated in favor of MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB
     */
    public static final int RAW_AMR = 3;

    /** AMR NB file format */
    public static final int AMR_NB = 3;

    /** AMR WB file format */
    public static final int AMR_WB = 4;

    /** @hide AAC ADIF file format */
    public static final int AAC_ADIF = 5;

    /** AAC ADTS file format */
    public static final int AAC_ADTS = 6;

    /** @hide Stream over a socket, limited to a single stream */
    public static final int OUTPUT_FORMAT_RTP_AVP = 7;

    /** H.264/AAC data encapsulated in MPEG2/TS */
    public static final int MPEG_2_TS = 8;

    /** VP8/VORBIS data in a WEBM container */
    public static final int WEBM = 9;
```